# data.data for reading my json

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-factory, angularjs-http

I have this factory:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testCon').factory('UserService', function ($http) {
   return {
       getAll: function () {
           return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/user');
       }
   }
});
```

And this controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testCon').controller('UserController', function ($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.users = [];
    UserService.getAll().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.users = data.data;
        }, function (err) {

        }
    );
});
```

Can I somehow avoid the `data.data` I would like to have only `data`. What is it that forces me to do `data.data` in order to see it in the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can't avoid that. You could make that as one time change by returning  only a `response.data` from `getAll` method. Then all the consumer will get direct data.

**Code**

```
angular.module('testCon').factory('UserService', function ($http) {
   return {
       getAll: function () {
           return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/user').then(function(response){
                return response.data
           });
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: @btmach Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testCon').factory('UserService', function ($http) {
   return {
       getAll: function () {
           return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/user').then(function (response) {
               return response.data;
           });
       }
   }
});
```

Then keep the other function as:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testCon').controller('UserController', function ($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.users = [];
    UserService.getAll().then(
        function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        }, function (err) {

        }
    );
});
```

What happens is that the first promise return is chained with the second then(..) but the second one gets the extracted data. It's a cool thing about promises.